# How to specify optional cookie parameter in Swagger contract?

Tags: spring, cookies, swagger, swagger-codegen

My problem is pretty straightforward: I want to be able to specify an optional cookie parameter in a GET request using Swagger. No matter what I do it is always marked as required in the generated API.

I defined my parameter this way in my contract:

```
        - name: pagination_cookie
          in: cookie
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
            format: byte
```

And here is the generated API:

```
@Parameter(name = "pagination_cookie", description = "", schema = @Schema(description = "")) @CookieValue("pagination_cookie") byte[] paginationCookie
```

All the other parameters, which are query params in this instance, are marked optional as they should. It seems to bug only for cookie params.

Is this a known issue ? I haven't been able to find much help on the internet. I would very much prefer to be able to mark this parameter as optional instead of having to specify an empty value for it each time...

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !